# How to inject services into actors using the Play 2.4?

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, akka, guice

I am able to inject services into my Application class with no issues. But somehow I am unable to inject into the actors themselves.

My actor:

```
class PollerCrow @Inject()(
     @Named("pollService") pollService: PollService[List[ChannelSftp#LsEntry]]
     , @Named("redisStatusService") redisStatusService: StatusService
     , @Named("dynamoDBStatusService") dynamoDbStatusService: StatusService
) extends BaseCrow {
... impl and stuff ...
}
```

My actor's companion object:

```
object PollerCrow extends NamedActor {
  override def name: String = this.getClass.getSimpleName

  val filesToProcess = ConfigFactory.load().getString("poller.crow.files.to.process")    
  def props = Props[PollerCrow]
}
```

I'm getting the following when I run it:

```
IllegalArgumentException: no matching constructor found on class watcher.crows.PollerCrow for arguments []
```

How can I fix this?

Edit:

I have binded my actors:

```
class ActorModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {

  override def configure() {
    bindPollerActors()
  }

  private def PollActors() = {
    bindActor[PollerCrow](PollerCrow.name)
  }
}
```

Edit 2:

Additional details to the class:

```
abstract class BaseCrow extends Crow with Actor with ActorLogging

class PollerCrow @Inject()(
            @Named(ServiceNames.PollService) pollService: PollService[List[ChannelSftp#LsEntry]]
          , @Named(ServiceNames.RedisStatusService) redisStatusService: StatusService
          , @Named(ServiceNames.DynamoDbStatusService) dynamoDbStatusService: StatusService
) extends BaseCrow {

  override def receive: Receive = {
    ...
  }
}

object PollerCrow extends NamedActor {
  override def name: String = this.getClass.getSimpleName

  def props = Props[PollerCrow]
}

trait NamedActor {
  def name: String
  final def uniqueGeneratedName: String = name + Random.nextInt(10000)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might to make `Guice` aware of you actors. This is clean approach:

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaGuiceSupport


class ActorModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  override def configure(): Unit =  {
    bindActor[YourActor]("your-actor")
  }
}

@Singleton
class YourActor @Inject()(yourService: IYourService) extends Actor {

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg => unhandled(msg)
  }

}
```

And `application.conf`:

```
play.modules {
  enabled += "ActorModule"
}
```

For those who don't want to hassle, just call injector directly and don't forget to import `Application` to scope:

```
Play.application.injector.instanceOf[YourService]
Play.application.injector.instanceOf(BindingKey(classOf[YourService]).qualifiedWith("your-name"));
```

Comment: that i have, class ActorModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport. i think guice is aware of the actor BUT it doesnt know how to inject services into the actor?

Comment: Your actor is an object. It needs to be class.

Comment: i updated OP... i have actor class then an actor object, tho both have the same name, does that matter?

Comment: Not sure how `Guice` handles companion objects.

Comment: i was able to get things working as a stand alone scala app following https://github.com/rocketraman/activator-akka-scala-guice#master, but when i ported things over to the play app, everything just broke =/

Comment: I am updating my answer with more flexible approach.

Comment: I can work with that. sorry but how would i deal with Named services?

Comment: this seems to be working(no longer throwing that error) but my actor is not receiving the message =/ thanks for your help on this!